# Oracle sql query : implementing an equation into a select group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following weighted average equation I'm trying to put into the select clause

(( operating_hrsA * component countA ) + ( operating_hrsC * component countB ) + ( operating_hrsC * component countC )) / total compont_countABC

The select I'm trying to put it into is:

```
 SELECT reporting_date_from,
            reporting_date_to,
            b_name,
            oflag,
            component_type,
            SUM (component_count) AS component_count,
            --AVG (average_operating_hours) AS average_operating_hours,
            sum((average_operating_hours * component_count) / sum(component_count))  AS average_operating_hours


       FROM DEVICE
       where reporting_date_From = '01-JAN-2017' and b_name like '430%' 
   GROUP BY reporting_date_from,
            reporting_date_to,
            b_name,
            oflag,
            component_type;
```

error I'm getting is :

> Error at line 1 ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

table schema : 
column              |   data type |    Null ? 
reporting_date_From  date  N 
reporting_date_to    date  N 
b_name               varchar2(100 byte)  Y 
oflag                varchar2(50 byte)   Y 
component_type       varchar2(50 byte) Y 
average_operating_hours number         Y

data sample
[image: data sample]
any ideas what I'm doing wrong with this calculation?
thanks in advance

Comment: seems you have nested  sum ..

Comment: are nested sum()'s not allowed in a select?

Comment: Generally nested sums are not allowed, there is one exception to that rule, but your query is not this case.

Comment: not directly  ... you should select the firts leve sum and then perform the seconnd leve

Comment: can you provide an example on how to do that?  really appreciate the help

Comment: can you show the sample data from the table? or atleast show the table structure.

Comment: sample data added

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subselect for get the result and then perform the calculation that implies  nested  sum eg:

```
select  reporting_date_from,
            reporting_date_to,
            b_name,
            oflag,
            component_type,
            component_count, 
            average_operating_hours, 
            my_value/component_count as average_operating_hours
  from(           
      SELECT reporting_date_from,
              reporting_date_to,
              b_name,
              oflag,
              component_type,
              SUM (component_count) AS component_count,
              AVG (average_operating_hours) AS average_operating_hours,
              sum((average_operating_hours * component_count) )  AS my_value,

         FROM DEVICE
         where reporting_date_From = '01-JAN-2017' and b_name like '430%' 
     GROUP BY reporting_date_from,
              reporting_date_to,
              b_name,
              oflag,
              component_type

    )  t
    ;
```

Comment: I keep getting a ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: nevermind.. the comma was throwing it off. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a window function. Change the `partition by` columns if needed based on the table structure and the desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
reporting_date_from,
reporting_date_to,
b_name,
oflag,
component_type,
sum(component_count) over(partition by reporting_date_from,reporting_date_to,b_name,oflag) AS component_count,
sum(average_operating_hours * component_count) over(partition by reporting_date_from,reporting_date_to,b_name,oflag)
/ sum(component_count) over()  AS average_operating_hours,
FROM DEVICE
where reporting_date_From = '01-JAN-2017' and b_name like '430%'
```

Comment: may I ask why do you use select Distinct .. ?

Comment: to get distinct rows in the output..remove it and observe the results and you'll understand.

Comment: did you leave out the group by clause on purpose?   when I add it back in it throws an error:  Not a group by expression

Comment: you don't need `group by` for this query. look up window functions and how they work.